# Synchronizing Visual Studio Code and Visual Studio 2019 preferences/settings

Tags: ide, visual-studio-2019, visual-studio-code

I was wondering whether there is an easy way to synchronize your preferences/settings across VS Code and VS 2019?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can go to Tools -> Options -> Environement -> Keyboard

[image]

Answer (score 0):

---

## Syncing Settings Across VS Code & VS 2022

---

I think I have a pretty good idea of what you're asking for, and I would say that they don't have what you are thinking to have. Like, if you wonder that since they are both funded by Microsoft dollars, that there maybe some sort of interoperability, but there's not. Many people have have been hoping for some time to see Visual Studio work in harmony with V.S. Code, but I don't think that will ever happen like many people are hoping it will. The reason is, they are fundamentally — at the very core of what they are — very different beasts. While, as I pointed out, they are both developed by Microsoft dollars, and they  are both ***"Development Environments"***, they are not both ***"Integrated Environments"***, and there in lies the difference that makes them worlds apart.

Visual Studio (the IDE) is considered to be an IDE — integrated is the keyword here — because it integrates into the projects that are built using Visual Studio as the Development Environment. Visual Studio Code does not integrate into projects, instead it allows you to structure the project, provide the compiler, debugger, and things like a build system, RTE, REPL, libraries, modules, plugins, the Languages themselves, etc... You are the master of your own environment with V.S. Code, and where developers have much more control over their projects using a non-integrated dev-env, especially one that's non-proprietary, they also have to put in much more work, to produce many of the same programs that Visual Studio can practically generate for you.

So the point here is, that you can't really swap configurations between the two, not for the majority of configured **stuff**, however; that's not to say that some settings cannot not be swapped. Any configuration that can have the same values applied to it, whether the configuration is in VS Code, or Visual Studio 2022, would not be unique to Visual Studio, and VS Code, and has nothing to do with the fact that they are both backed by Microsoft. In fact, if you have a group of settings, and those settings exist in both environments, and are able to accept all the same values (they can't accept any different values in any env) then that configuration will port to environments far beyond Visual Studio Code & Visual Studio 2022, and will probably be configurable in over 90% of the Development Environments out there. And this is something that software engineers, programmers & web-developers/designers take advantage of already, and it's referred to by its filename...

---

## Dot-Editor-Config or `.editorconfig`

[image]

###### *"Above is the Dot-Editor-Config Project's Logo."*

EditorConfig, is a good gig, but it won't configure entire environments. Like most tools, the more you use it, the better you will get at making use of it. It seems to me that it is more useful across IDE's, as IDEs, as I explained above, work similarly  (obviously), so they have more settings in common. Editor config basically creates a medium for setting semantics. Since settings found in different **Development Environments** are often called something different in each environment, what the **`.editorconfig`** file does, is it gives a single name for each of the variation of the setting that ports across environments, and gives a single place to configure the setting, allowing you to take one file from IDE to IDE. Like I said though, there is only so much it will configure, and it works better between IDE's than between IDE and Editor, at least IMHO.

##### Check Editor Config out, and see what you think.

I used to use it mainly to configure formatting across C++ projects, but ***CLang's CLang-Format Tool*** has become such a good tool that I did away with it.

This link will take you to the **Dot-Editor-Config GitHub Repository**, where you can find the `.editorconfig` extensions for...

- ##### VS Code
- ##### Visual Studio
- ##### JetBrains
- ##### Emacs
- ##### Vim

###### ...and probably many more.

I did some research, or lack-of I should say, after authoring this. I couldn't find any other options out there. There really isn't a lot in the way to help in porting configurations, except for .editorconfig, and really .editorconfig won't do much between an IDE & Editor than configure formatting styles. You can get that same functionality with Prettier, CLang, ESLint, and many other tools. Editor-config doesn't just configure its-self though, like a formatter does, so I am sure you can find some extras it targets, but It's not so much that I use it. A lot of people do, though.

---

### [Dot Editor Config GitHub Repo](https://github.com/editorconfig/)

---

Answer (score 0):

Watching this thought as well.  I've been working in VSCode for a few years off and on as needed.  But the full VS IDE (2022 currently) is both more complicated and more capable, so I'm running both.

Then realized that many of the extensions may (should?) be cross-usable, but still digging through that to determine what 'reality' looks like.

Sensible question though.